# Parse nested JSON in R

Tags: json, r

I was trying to parse several JSONs on a dataframe on R, and I failed miserably.

The files were quite different. Some were quite simple and easy to parse (with library jsonlite), other were heavily nested and I got into much trouble to parse them. I eventually did it (very badly) but it was pain in the ass. And if I use another JSON with different nesting... It doesn't work anymore.

I googled quite a lot and I couldn't find any nice tool for that. There was tidyjson but it's not available anymore. On python with pandas it is simpler but I would like to stay with R.

Question: is there any library that you know of to do this? Or can you recommend an external tool to pre-process the JSONs and then load the result in R?

Thanks in advance! Cheers.